# Trying to return an array of all object using boolean and function

Tags: javascript

So here I created a function called filterQuestionsByType where I take in 2 arguments, which are the submissions in isEssayQuestion. So what I am trying to do is when called like filterQuestionsByType(submissions, false) I am trying to return an array of all the submission types with the appropriate type. so This particular call in my example should result in a list of all the submission where false is true for isEssayQuestion and return

question: 'What anatomical structure connects the stomach to the mouth?',
response: 'Esophagus',
isCorrect: true,
isEssayQuestion: false
else return an array opposite boolean

My issue is that my current code is not returning the whole list. I think it stops after the first loop. I'm not sure why I am having such an hard time figuring where I went wrong. I really need help..
here's my code

```
const submissions = [
  {
    question: 'What is the phase where chromosomes line up in mitosis?',
    response: 'Metaphase',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
   },
  {
    question: 'What anatomical structure connects the stomach to the mouth?',
    response: 'Esophagus',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
   },
   {
    question: 'What are lysosomes?',
    response: 'A lysosome is a membrane-bound organelle found in many animal cells. They are 
spherical vesicles that contain hydrolytic enzymes that can break down many kinds of biomolecules.',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: true
  },
  {
    question: 'True or False: Prostaglandins can only constrict blood vessels.',
     response: 'True',
     isCorrect: false,
     isEssayQuestion: false
   }
 ];
```

Here's my actual code

```
function filterQuestionsByType(submissions, isEssayQuestion){

  let filterQuestionsByType = {}

  for (i = 0; i < submissions.length; i++){

if (submissions[i].isEssayQuestion === true){
 filterQuestionsByType[submissions[i].isEssayQuestion] = submissions[i]; 

} else{
  if (submissions[i].isEssayQuestion === false){
    filterQuestionsByType[submissions[i].isEssayQuestion] = submissions[i];
  }
}
}

 return filterQuestionsByType;
```

}
Here's my sample output

```
  {
    question: 'What is the phase where chromosomes line up in mitosis?',
    response: 'Metaphase',
    isCorrect: true,
     isEssayQuestion: false
   },
  {
    question: 'What anatomical structure connects the stomach to the 
 mouth?',
    response: 'Esophagus',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  },
   {
    question: 'True or False: Prostaglandins can only constrict blood 
     vessels.',
      response: 'True',
     isCorrect: false,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  }
]
```

Comment: `where false is true` what do you mean by that ? Can you clarify more please !

Comment: can you share a sample output that you require

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will check if there are any objects with property `isEssayQuestion` is equal to your desired input if it couldn't find any it will return the opposite

```js
const submissions = [ { question: "What is the phase where chromosomes line up in mitosis?", response: "Metaphase", isCorrect: true, isEssayQuestion: false, }, { question: "What anatomical structure connects the stomach to the mouth?", response: "Esophagus", isCorrect: true, isEssayQuestion: false, }, { question: "What are lysosomes?", response: "A lysosome is a membrane-bound organelle found in many animal cells. They are spherical vesicles that contain hydrolytic enzymes that can break down many kinds of biomolecules.", isCorrect: true, isEssayQuestion: true, }, { question: "True or False: Prostaglandins can only constrict blood vessels.", response: "True", isCorrect: false, isEssayQuestion: false, }, ];

function filterQuestionsByType(submissions, isEssayQuestion) {
  res = submissions.filter((o) => o.isEssayQuestion == isEssayQuestion);
  return res.length > 0
    ? res
    : submissions.filter((o) => o.isEssayQuestion != isEssayQuestion);
}

console.log(filterQuestionsByType(submissions, false));
```

Comment: This is the code that runs properly. There are techniques that I don't quite understand just yet like res = submissions.filter((o) => o.isEssayQuestion == isEssayQuestion); I'm going to look further into this

Comment: @MarayshaWashington My answer is exactly doing the same thing as this answer with less code - Not sure how this run properly. You still need to put `false` or `true` in this as well to get the expected results.

Comment: I am happy to explain  `res = submissions.filter((o) => o.isEssayQuestion == isEssayQuestion)` all what it does is it iterates through the submissions object and it filters any object that has `isEssayQuestion` is equal to  your desired boolean input `o` is just short for object  `o.isEssayQuestion`  will get the property of the current object

Comment: @AlwaysHelping your answer is not what OP wanted

Comment: @Sven.hig No no please do not take me wrong. I am just trying to understand only from the OP. Your exactly is exactly as mine just looking for the magical difference in both!

Comment: @MarayshaWashington if you need any clarification feel free to ask me i will be happy to respond :)

Comment: @Sven.hig  OK I think I understand. is that line the equivalent to the for loop i wrote looping through submissions combined with that very long if statement. I do not understand why I am not being taught this method instead it seems much more efficient

Comment: @MaraeciaWashington Yes for iteration the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method is the same as the 'forEach' method. However, they are different, the `filter` method filters every element in the array that meets the condition you want and then the callback returns an array with the elements that passed the test, forEach allows you to only iterate through the array and it's callback doesn't return anything. I hope that's clear, let me know if you have anymore questions

Answer (score 1):

You can do this **two ways**. You can choose what suits you best.

**Using simply `filter` function** (one liner)

You can simply change the `false` to `true` in `getSubs()` and you will get the question where is `isEssayQuestion` = `true`

Live Demo:

```js
const submissions = [{
    question: 'What is the phase where chromosomes line up in mitosis?',
    response: 'Metaphase',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  },
  {
    question: 'What anatomical structure connects the stomach to the mouth?',
    response: 'Esophagus',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  },
  {
    question: 'What are lysosomes?',
    response: 'A lysosome is a membrane-bound organelle found in many animal cells. They are spherical vesicles that contain hydrolytic enzymes that can break down many kinds of biomolecules.',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: true
  },
  {
    question: 'True or False: Prostaglandins can only constrict blood vessels.',
    response: 'True',
    isCorrect: false,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  }
];

let getSubs = (type) => submissions.filter(x => x.isEssayQuestion === type)

console.log(getSubs(false))
```

**Using `forEach` function**

You can simply use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop and add `index` of each `obj` found in the new object and return `filterQuestionsByType` from the function.

You can simply change the `false` to `true` in `filterQuestionsByType()` and you will get the question where is `isEssayQuestion` = `true`

Live Demo:

```js
const submissions = [{
    question: 'What is the phase where chromosomes line up in mitosis?',
    response: 'Metaphase',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  },
  {
    question: 'What anatomical structure connects the stomach to the mouth?',
    response: 'Esophagus',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  },
  {
    question: 'What are lysosomes?',
    response: 'A lysosome is a membrane-bound organelle found in many animal cells. They are spherical vesicles that contain hydrolytic enzymes that can break down many kinds of biomolecules.',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: true
  },
  {
    question: 'True or False: Prostaglandins can only constrict blood vessels.',
    response: 'True',
    isCorrect: false,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  }
];

function filterQuestionsByType(submissions, type) {
  let filterQuestionsByType = {}
  submissions.forEach(function(sub, index) {
    if (sub.isEssayQuestion == type) {
      filterQuestionsByType[sub.isEssayQuestion + index] = sub;
    }
  })
  return filterQuestionsByType;
}

console.log(filterQuestionsByType(submissions, false))
```

Comment: I'm also trying to create an else statement. that will also return an list of array that isEssayQuestion = true. I'm calling with either true or false

Comment: @MarayshaWashington Yes! my answer will cover both `true` and `false` You just need to pass the the `true` or `false` option to the function and you will the results you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are trying to do would be easier if you use the filter method, something like this:

```
const filteredQuestions = submissions.filter((question, questionIndex)=>{
    if (question.isEssayQuestion)// You don't need to do the === true
        return true;
    return false;
})
```

This will give you the array of questions that pass the validation.